# Does SQS return all messages with the following code?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I am trying to understand what would be the behavior of the following code:

```
    // receive messages from the queue
    List<Message> messages = sqs.receiveMessage(queueUrl).getMessages();

    // delete messages from the queue
    for (Message m : messages) {
        sqs.deleteMessage(queueUrl, m.getReceiptHandle());
    }
```

1. Will it return all the messages in the queue ?
2. If not, how to loop through all the messages in the queue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- No, as Mark said it only return up to 10 messages.

2- You have two options:

First:
Send your request every 1 minute(for example) and get messages in your queue, process them and delete. So, your function retrieves all of them after a few minutes.

Second:
Use AWS Lambda function for process your queue.
For more info read the following doc:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs.html

If you want to process a lot of messages, so the second method is better, because of performance and costs. (AWS charge you based on your total request to SQS, so in the first method if you have not any messages in your queue, your app send the request every one minute without any return)

Answer (score 2):

No it does not, a `receiveMessage` request will return at most 10 messages.